# C++ Vector subscript out of range dirent

Tags: c++

```
public:vector<vector<string>> cont;
void memContent(string path, int f){
    DIR *dir;
    struct dirent *ent; int j = 0;
    if ((dir = opendir(path.c_str())) != NULL) {
        while ((ent = readdir(dir)) != NULL) {
            for (int i = 0; i < ext_no; i++)
            if (strstr(ent->d_name, ext[i].c_str()))
            {

                cont[f].push_back(ent->d_name);
            }
        }
        closedir(dir);
    }
}
main(){

for (int i = 0; i < f.dir_no; i++)
    f.memContent(f.dir[i], i);
}
```

i have a vector of vectors which should get all files from a number of folder but i keep getting an error about the size of the vector;
Btw: i used "f" to know the current folder and i have the paths in other vector

Comment: Don't add the index when you push_back. Just do cont.push_back

Comment: are you sure ? i mean the structure of the vector is cont[folder][file] .. and i'm only trying to push_back the name of the files for every folder

Comment: @hallelujah Did you ensure that the `vector` at least was `resized()` properly to store something at index `f`?

Comment: Please add the definition of cont then to your description.

Comment: Try to use cont.at(f) instead of cont[f], then you will get an exception if there is no element f.

Comment: i used cont.at(f) and indeed, i got an exception

Comment: Then you apparently haven't push back the folders.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Before the loop you need to ensure your `cont` vector contains one vector for each directory:

```
cont.resize(dir_no)
```